# Insert a PowerPoint content add-in using COM/PIA

Tags: com, powerpoint, office-js, pia

We have a desktop app communicating with the running PowerPoint app through COM (using [NetOffice](https://netoffice.io/) wrapper) which is able to create, modify slides and shapes in the opened document by calling COM methods. We also have a modern JS-based content add-in, which we would like to configure and insert to a specific slide from that desktop app (like a standard shape). I went through the entire [object model documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint/object-model), but didn't find anything regarding the content add-ins.

So, my question is: It is somehow possible to insert a [modern/JS PowerPoint content add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/) (or even install it if missing to PowerPoint) using the COM/PIA  API?

Answer (score 2):

No, the PowerPoint extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.